# How to have no more than 20 Entity references to another content type?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type with a entity reference to another content type/view. The current possible relations could be 1,2,3 .... until 10 or unlimited. These are given in the field attributes screens.

I need 20. After that the user is not allowed to add another field in the gui.

Any solutions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select unlimited as possible relations. Then, using a custom module, you can alter the node edit form to don't allow more than 20 items.

To do this, implement hook form alter:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // do magic.
}
```

Inside you have to:

- Check the if the relations field has 20 item; if yes
  delete the element widget that adds another one (so user don't get confused because it seems more items can be added).
- Add a new validate handler to check related items are less than
  21.

Comment: I add dpm($form) in the hook to investigate. However when pushing add item the form is not refreshing (problably ajax processed?). So then this will not work is it?

Comment: The form workflow is complex, more when AJAX is involved. But form should be rebuilt upon clicking on add button, and all form alters should called. Don't trus dpm() in ajax calls, sometimes dpm output is lost. Use xdebug (proces debugging) or use dd function. dd() is like dpm but writes ouptut to drupal_debug.txt file in the tmp drupal directory (defined in media config page).

Comment: works perfect thxs